# Find by id returns None even if div exists

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need a little help, please.
I try to get some data from a site and I don't succeed. Although the div exists, it returns None to me. Do you know why? This is the site: https://iasi.inoras.ro/evenimente/

I would not like to use Selenium, is there another method?

[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://iasi.inoras.ro/evenimente/"

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

content = soup.find(id = 'evcal_list')
for i in content:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to scrap?

Comment: can you show what you tried so far?

Comment: `I would not like to use selenium` - then why you have tagged `Selenium` ? Cypress is another tool you can think of

Comment: Are you waiting for more answers before accepting either of the two working ones you have already got @rafaelelmundo?

Comment: What do you mean by `no, no thx`? What I meant is if any of the following answers solves your issue make sure to accept that answer by pressing the grayed out checkmark. This is [how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/673712) you can.

Answer (score 2):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript. You can use this example how to load it with `requests` module:

```py
import json
import requests
import datetime as dt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://iasi.inoras.ro/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

payload = {
    "action": "eventon_init_load",
    "global[calendars][]": "EVODV",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][_cal_evo_rtl]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][accord]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][cal_id]": "",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][cal_init_nonajax]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][calendar_type]": "daily",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][day_incre]": "0",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][dv_view_style]": "def",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][etc_override]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][etop_month]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][evc_open]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][event_count]": "0",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][event_location]": "all",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][event_order]": "DESC",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][event_organizer]": "all",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][event_past_future]": "all",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][event_tag]": "all",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][event_type]": "all",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][event_type_2]": "all",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][event_type_3]": "all",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][event_type_4]": "all",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][event_type_5]": "all",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][eventtop_style]": "0",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][exp_jumper]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][exp_so]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][filter_relationship]": "AND",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][filter_show_set_only]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][filter_type]": "default",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][filters]": "yes",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][fixed_day]": "17",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][fixed_month]": "5",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][fixed_year]": "2021",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][focus_end_date_range]": "1622505599",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][focus_start_date_range]": "1619827200",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][ft_event_priority]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][header_title]": "",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][hide_arrows]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][hide_date_box]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][hide_empty_months]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][hide_end_time]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][hide_ft]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][hide_month_headers]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][hide_mult_occur]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][hide_past]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][hide_past_by]": "ee",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][hide_so]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][hide_sort_options]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][ics]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][jumper]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][jumper_count]": "5",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][jumper_offset]": "0",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][lang]": "L1",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][layout_changer]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][mapformat]": "roadmap",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][mapiconurl]": "",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][maps_load]": "yes",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][mapscroll]": "true",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][mapzoom]": "18",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][members_only]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][ml_priority]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][mo1st]": "",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][month_incre]": "0",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][number_of_months]": "1",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][only_ft]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][pec]": "",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][s]": "",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][search]": "",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][sep_month]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][show_et_ft_img]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][show_limit]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][show_limit_ajax]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][show_limit_paged]": "1",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][show_limit_redir]": "",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][show_repeats]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][show_upcoming]": "0",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][show_year]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][sort_by]": "sort_date",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][tile_bg]": "0",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][tile_count]": "2",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][tile_height]": "0",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][tile_style]": "0",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][tiles]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][ux_val]": "0",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][view_switcher]": "no",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][wpml_l1]": "",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][wpml_l2]": "",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][wpml_l3]": "",
    "cals[evcal_calendar_172][sc][yl_priority]": "no",
}

data = requests.post(api_url, data=payload).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for d in data["cals"]["evcal_calendar_172"]["json"]:
    start = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(d["event_start_unix"]).strftime(
        "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    )
    end = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(d["event_start_unix"]).strftime(
        "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    )
    print(start, end, BeautifulSoup(d["event_title"], "html.parser").text)
```

Prints:

```
2021-05-31 07:00:00 2021-05-31 07:00:00 Expoziție în aer liber: „Fryderyk Chopin – viața și creația”
2021-05-30 19:00:00 2021-05-30 19:00:00 IAȘI | Puricele în ureche
2021-05-30 19:00:00 2021-05-30 19:00:00 PURICELE IN URECHE(La cererea publicului)
2021-05-30 19:00:00 2021-05-30 19:00:00 Farmazonul din Hârlău
2021-05-30 11:00:00 2021-05-30 11:00:00 Făt frumos din Lacrimă
2021-05-30 07:00:00 2021-05-30 07:00:00 Expoziție în aer liber: „Fryderyk Chopin – viața și creația”
2021-05-29 19:00:00 2021-05-29 19:00:00 IAȘI | Puricele în ureche
2021-05-29 19:00:00 2021-05-29 19:00:00 Un tramvai numit Dorință
2021-05-29 18:30:00 2021-05-29 18:30:00 Chirița în provinție // Sala Mare
2021-05-29 11:00:00 2021-05-29 11:00:00 Magic Dreamcatcher | Teatro Blu
2021-05-29 07:00:00 2021-05-29 07:00:00 Expoziție în aer liber: „Fryderyk Chopin – viața și creația”
2021-05-28 19:00:00 2021-05-28 19:00:00 Un tramvai numit Dorință | LIVE STREAMING
2021-05-28 18:30:00 2021-05-28 18:30:00 Chirița în provinție // Sala Mare
2021-05-28 07:00:00 2021-05-28 07:00:00 Expoziție în aer liber: „Fryderyk Chopin – viața și creația”

...and so on.
```

Comment: Well the question is `Although the div exists, it returns None to me. Do you know why?` not how to scrape it.

Comment: @cruisepandey *"The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript."* BeautifulSoup doesn't render JavaScript, so it doesn't see the `<div>`

Comment: Thank you very much! where did you find the json file?

Comment: @rafaelelmundo When you open Firefox Developer Tools -> Network tab and reload the page, you can see the request there (you can filter it via URL/type, chrome has something similar).

Comment: @AndrejKesely haha, I searched before asking the question, but I didn't know I had to reload the page to appear. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrejKesely how could I take / display besides the title (even_title), the start time, the end time (they are wrong, by the way), the image, the description, the location and the link from the "learn more" button? Basically, I need all the information that appears when I click on an event on the site. I'm sorry to call on you again, but I really need it because I've never worked with it before, but I want to learn.

Comment: @rafaelelmundo Uncomment this `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))` and see what information is inside (there are lots of it). All the images/links are inside.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I wrote in a file but I don't know how to extract the information ... for d on ["cals"] ["evcal_calendar_172"] ["html"]: (???) I don't know how to get it from here, for absolutely each event / div with id = event_number. What can I do to help me? : ((

Comment: @rafaelelmundo The variable `data` is normal python dictionary. So `data["cals"]["evcal_calendar_172"]["json"]` contains list of every event. Every element is a dictionary with various keys: `event_start_unix`, `event_end_unix`, `event_title` etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232534/discussion-between-rafaelelmundo-and-andrej-kesely).

Comment: @AndrejKesely but the data that I need as a I say (image, link to facebook, description, and all the rest, are not there in that dictionary - data["cals"]["evcal_calendar_172"]["json"]

Comment: @rafaelelmundo  If you explicitly show the items you want to retrieve and give an example row of output you avoid wasting people's time who are trying to help you.

Comment: @QHarr https://imgur.com/a/HlGuL1F I want all the data that appears when I click on an event title on the site. Andrej showed me that I can get the title from that dictionary but I can't find everything I want. I can't find the picture, the description, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the data from a specific date you will need:

1 Use Selenium.

2 Use explicit waits: `from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait`

3 Wait for the date to appear and click it. However because of Captchta the date is not always clickable, so I used some scrolling () scrolled to events dates main class.

4 Wait for events to load and **scrape** the resulting data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get("https://iasi.inoras.ro/evenimente/")
assert "Oras" in driver.title
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
cal = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".eventon_daily_in")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", cal)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p[data-date='20']"))).click()
events = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".eventon_list_event.evo_eventtop.dayevent")))
names = []
for event in events:
    name = event.find_element_by_css_selector(" .evcal_desc2.evcal_event_title").text
    names.append(name)
print(*names, sep='\n')
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Result:

```
FENOMEN TROPICAL
ORAȘUL
WHITE JUNE JASMINE
ONLINE & LIVE: ȘTEFAN AFLOROAEI ÎN DIALOG CU AUREL CODOBAN ȘI GEORGE BONDOR
COLIVIA // SALA MARE
ATELIER DE PICTURĂ PENTRU ADULȚI
ATELIER DE PICTURĂ „(AUTO)PORTRET”
INTARCARE - EMOTII, DIFICULTATI SI SOLUTII
EXPOZIȚIE ÎN AER LIBER: „FRYDERYK CHOPIN – VIAȚA ȘI CREAȚIA”
RIDICĂ BARIERA, ALEGE CARIERA!
```

To get events that are not visible in calendar, you'll need to click > button and wait for events to load.